Question about Higher Dimensional Extension of Coordinate Frames
This is a bit of a weird and I don't think a well-defined question, but I'll try my best to articulate it:
Suppose we have two orthonormal coordinate frames, in reference to a world coordinate system, where one is defined by the basis [1 0 0], [0 1 0], [0 0 1] and the second is defined by ($x_1(t)$, $y_1(t)$, $z_1(t))$, $(x_2(t)$, $y_2(t)$, $z_2(t))$, and $(x_3(t)$, $y_3(t)$, $z_3(t)$), where there is a time dependence on each of the basis coordinates for the second frame. Is there an extension/(how would one find it) of the 3d space to a higher dimensional space where the two frames are 'near identical' up to a coordinate difference only dependent on t?
Like one such example is the transformation of the two initial frames to some [$x'_1$, $y'_1$, $z'_1$, $t'_1(t)$], [$x'_2$, $y'_2$, $z'_2$, $t'_2(t)$], [$x'_3$, $y'_3$, $z'_3$, $t'_3(t)$].

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

Let me offer a trivial answer, not because I think it'll satisfy you, but because it might help you refine your question. The map $(x, y, z) \mapsto (0, 0, 0, x, y, z)$ will map each set of coordinates to orthonormal vectors in $\Bbb{R}^6$, and have the property that the first three coordinates of each transformed basis are fixed. I'm assuming that this is not what you're looking for; why is that?
